# How can I get the second column to line up perfectly using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make the second column line up perfectly when I run the following code:

```
import math
x = 1.0 
while x <= 65536.0: 
  print x, '\t\t', math.log(x)/math.log(2.0) 
  x = x * 2.0
```

However the three bottom lines of the second column are always tabbed an additional time in relation to the previous lines, regardless of how many '\t's I use.

How can I fix this?

Comment: your first column gets bigger so pushes the second column over

Comment: That is how the tab character works.

Comment: Example in Python docs dubbed [Aligning the text and specifying a width](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `str.format` and line up on the inside:

```
import math
x = 1.0
while x <= 65536.0:
    print "{:7}    {}".format(x, math.log(x)/math.log(2.0))
    x = x * 2.0

    1.0    0.0
    2.0    1.0
    4.0    2.0
    8.0    3.0
   16.0    4.0
   32.0    5.0
   64.0    6.0
  128.0    7.0
  256.0    8.0
  512.0    9.0
 1024.0    10.0
 2048.0    11.0
 4096.0    12.0
 8192.0    13.0
16384.0    14.0
32768.0    15.0
65536.0    16.0
```

Or use `zfill()` to pad with zeros:

```
 print "{}    {}".format(str(x).zfill(7),math.log(x)/math.log(2.0))


00001.0    0.0
00002.0    1.0
00004.0    2.0
00008.0    3.0
00016.0    4.0
00032.0    5.0
00064.0    6.0
00128.0    7.0
00256.0    8.0
00512.0    9.0
01024.0    10.0
02048.0    11.0
04096.0    12.0
08192.0    13.0
16384.0    14.0
32768.0    15.0
65536.0    16.0
```